# How can i have ExpandableRecyclerView and Recycler View at the same time?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

i have a doubt about ExpandableRecyclerView and RecyclerView:

I'm trying to make a menu using these two classes' children but i think i can't find anything that can add more "rows", this is what i've made:

```
RecyclerView recycler = findViewById(R.id.recycle);
    LinearLayoutManager manager= new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    RecyclerView.ItemAnimator animator= recycler.getItemAnimator();
    ((DefaultItemAnimator)animator).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
    adapter= new ExpandableItemAdapter(setItems());
    recycler.setLayoutManager(manager);
    recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter= new SingleItemAdapter(this,setSingleItem());
```

But when i try to add an adapter it replaces the older.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you trying to add two different adapters to a single RecyclerView?

Comment: something like that!? i really dunno. i know that with 1 recyclerview i can make more than 1 expandablerecyclerview or more than 1 recyclerview but i can't put a expandablerecyclerview and recyclerview at the same time

Comment: Okay, what you are trying to achieve is a bit more complicated. I don't mind helping, if you still need help, let me know.

Comment: Yes plz, i still need help for it. I searching for about 5 days for information but unfortunatly i can't find anything this topic or similar